# Unable for format Date time into Specific format using PHP

Tags: php, date

I have got date time input string in below format

```
Wednesday 9th 2018 12.00am
```

And I want to convert it to something like this

```
2018-03-09
```

I tried using strtotime function but it didn't work.
Any idea?

Comment: What is `9th` define ?

Comment: It's a day. I highly doubt the issue is because month is not mentioned anywhere?

Comment: _"I highly doubt the issue is because month is not mentioned anywhere"_ - Why would you doubt that? PHP isn't psychic. Try to add "march" after "9th" and you'll see what's what.

Comment: first you need to normalize in to date(Wednesday 9th 2018 12.00am) while it's not a correct date. may be you look for echo date("l Y-m-d H:m:s");

Comment: As pointed out by @Jenil, converting that string _can't_ translate to 2018-03-09, since that is a Friday and not a Wednesday. Wrong input == wrong output.

Comment: Are you sure march is the correct month? May 9th is a wednsday.

Answer (score 0):

Without month specification PHP unable to select month for a date.
I prepared the solution as per adding month into your date input: **Wednesday 9th March 2018 12.00am**

```
<?php
$original_date = "Wednesday 9th March 2018 12.00am";
$pieces = explode(" ", $original_date);
$new_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($pieces[1]." ".$pieces[2].",".$pieces[3]));
echo $new_date;
```

Output: 2018-03-09

Demo : https://eval.in/970073

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already tried that, It will not work :(  Output of "date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Wednesday 9th March 2018 12.00am'));" would be "2018-03-14" not "2018-03-09".
Hope this helps.

Comment: That's because `9th` isn't a Wednesday, while 14th is. The date is invalid.

Comment: Yup, I know. So in that case concatenation is the only option. :)

Comment: I would argue that he only correct option is for the OP to fix the input string.

Comment: Please post the correct input string you trying to convey.

Comment: I got your points :) Question its self is incorrect, Wednesday 9th 2018 12.00am  its Friday ;) So it should be "Friday 9th 2018 12.00am" :)

Comment: Exactly. The OP can't expect to get the "correct" output from an invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

check the date you need to provide the correct date.

```
<?php

 $givendate = "Wednesday 7th March 2018 12.00am";
 echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($givendate));
?>
```

Comment: You forgot the `9th`

Comment: 9th means noting wednesday is in 7,14,21,28, we can not provide the wrong date

Comment: True. I think the OP should sort out the input data before we're trying to fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find what month has the 9th as a wednsday.
I loop through the months and add them to the string and see if the day of that month is the same as one in the string.
If it's true I add it to the "list" of possible dates.

```
$str = "Wednesday 9th 2018 12.00am";
$months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$day = $arr[1];
$parts = [$arr[0]. " ".$arr[1], $arr[2]. " ".$arr[3]];


Foreach($months as $m){
   $unix = strtotime($parts[0] . " " .$m . " " . $parts[1]);
   If(date("d", $unix) == substr($day,0,-2)) $res[]= date("Y-m-d", $unix);
}

Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/jc2HY

Comment: 1. Do not capitalize the first letter of functions and control structures 2. Don't use `strtotime()` and `Date()` for date manipulation, use `DateTime()` and its related classes 3. It is generally frowned upon to answer questions were the user has not shown any effort to solve the problem themselves